# Metatags are not shown if "index.php" is shared on Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, meta-tags

We have an app running on facebook. Metatags for sharing the link of the app are implemented correctly and working, as long as I am not sharing the index.php.

I implemented exactly the same content into three files:

```
index.php -> no image or description shown
start.php -> thumbnail and description shown
indextest.php -> thumbnail and description shown
```

My problem:
It must work with the index.php because most people are sharing via the path: http://apps.facebook.com/myapp

So does Facebook just not recognize any files named index.php?
And do you have any suggestions how to solve this?

Many thanks!

EDIT:
Ooookay! Thanks for all your help guys. It was indeed a caching problem, but not for the files. Every time a user shares a link, facebook saves the given thumbnail and description. This is just hillarious! Because the time until the cache is flushed can sum up to one week! So it would be a very bad idea if you shared a link of your site just to check how it looks, if it is not finished.

Fortunately this caching is case-sensitive, if you enter a letter in big, that you entered small, facebook will get new contents, but again just for this url.
My main url (with small letters) will still not work.

Check here for further information (quite important if you are into facebook development):
http://fbmhell.com/2010/10/breaking-facebook-share-cache/

I can answer the question after 8 hours.
But still you both helped me had to do with cache and I needed the url tool to find out about this specific caching ;-)

Comment: Did you add the meta-tags recently? Facebook may have an old cache on your index.php file, and therefore not showing any information, but in the cases of start and indextest, facebook did not have a cache.

Comment: Thought so as well, but I even changed contents in index.php and confirmed change via the source code output. Afterwards remoded it and uploaded the orginal file again, but no changes. Also cleared cache on my side as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooookay! Thanks for all your help guys. It was indeed a caching problem, but not for the files. Every time a user shares a link, facebook saves the given thumbnail and description. This is just hillarious! Because the time until the cache is flushed can sum up to one week! So it would be a very bad idea if you shared a link of your site just to check how it looks, if it is not finished.

Fortunately this caching is case-sensitive, if you enter a letter in big, that you entered small, facebook will get new contents, but again just for this url.
My main url (with small letters) will no

Check here for further information (quite important if you are into facebook development):
http://fbmhell.com/2010/10/breaking-facebook-share-cache/

Answer (score 1):

Try using OG tags:
`http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/`

e.g.:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Are already implemented. Like I said, all three files have the same content with the usual meta tags and the open graph tags. Just index.php does not work, which seems to conclude that the problem is the file name... But thanks anyway!

Comment: You can try to go to `http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint` and enter your link too see what facebook reads from your page.

Comment: Wow, thanks! But this is getting stranger and stranger! All three files show up with the same information (exactly as they should)! Image, title and description included, but still if I use share as link on wall, ther wont appear any information for index.php. Tested it with three accounts. The url is: http://apps.facebook.com/premiumsekttest/ feel free to test it!

Comment: Sorry, I have to go now. Hope you'll make it work! I had lots of problems with facebook's share too and the url linter helped me a lot to see what's going on. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you I was able to solve it! The tool was and will be a great help to me! But I guess I will have to answer the question by my own, your answer did not hit the spot for me. But many thanks!